# change hyperlink button status after Login

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I added a hyperlink button after buttons HOME and ABOUT
in a Silverlight 4 Business Application. what I want to do is that hiding the button before login and make it visible after an user login.

I would like to know how to change the status of the hyperlink button after an user Logins.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Silverlight Business Application template, installed with WCF RIA Services.  It has exactly this scenario in the template, which should give you some ideas on how to implement it even if you don't want to use RIA Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `bool` property to your class, which will be `true` if  button must be `visible` and `false` if `collapsed`. Then you need [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to convert `bool` to `visibility`.

This post is about that: [Using a value converter to bind to Visibility in the Silverlight data grid](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/)